# Red Black Tree Implementation Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, red-black-tree

I'm trying to implement a RBT using a textbooks pseudo code, but I am getting a null pointer exception. I tried adding checks for null, but it just crashes with another null somewhere further down. My guess is that I'm not supposed to have so many null checks to begin with (otherwise the pseudo code would have reflected that). Anyway, below are my relevant portions of code. I'd appreciate any help I can get at least narrowing down the problem:

```
public class RBtree {

    public static Node root; //root of RBT

    private class Node{
        private String key; //an identifying field inducing a total ordering
        private Node left; //left child (may be NULL)
        private Node right; //right child (may be NULL)
        private Node parent; //parent node (NULL for root)
        private String color;

        //constructor 
        public Node(String key){
            this.key = key;
            left = null;
            right = null;
            color = "red";

        }

    }

    public void addNode(String word){
        Node toInsert = new Node(word);
        Node parent = null;
        Node current = root;
        while(current != null){
            //System.out.println("root = " + root + " current = " + current);
            parent = current;
            if(toInsert.key.compareTo(current.key) > 0){
                current = current.left;
            }else{
                current = current.right;
            }
        }
        toInsert.parent = parent;
        if(parent == null){
            root = toInsert;
        }else if(toInsert.key.compareTo(parent.key) > 0){
            parent.left = toInsert;
        }else{
            parent.right = toInsert;
        }
        toInsert.left = null;
        toInsert.right = null;
        toInsert.color = "red";
        RBinsertFixUp(toInsert);

    }

    public void RBinsertFixUp(Node toFix){
        Node parent = null;
        while(toFix.parent.color.equals("red")){ //CRASH NULL POINTER
            if(toFix.parent.equals(toFix.parent.parent.left)){
                parent = toFix.parent.parent.right;     
                if(parent != null){
                    // begin case#1
                    if(parent.color.equals("red")){
                        toFix.parent.color = "black";
                        parent.color = "black";
                        toFix.parent.parent.color = "red";
                        toFix = toFix.parent.parent;
                    } //end case#1
                    else if(toFix.equals(toFix.parent.right)){ 
                        toFix = toFix.parent; //case#2
                        leftRotate(toFix.parent.parent); //case#2
                    }
                    toFix.parent.color = "black"; //case#3
                    toFix.parent.parent.color = "red"; //case#3
                    rightRotate(toFix.parent.parent); //case#3
                }
            }
            else{
                parent = toFix.parent.parent.left;      
                if(parent != null){
                    // begin case#1
                    if(parent.color.equals("red")){
                        toFix.parent.color = "black";
                        parent.color = "black";
                        toFix.parent.parent.color = "red";
                        toFix = toFix.parent.parent;
                    } //end case#1
                    else if(toFix.equals(toFix.parent.left)){ 
                        toFix = toFix.parent; //case#2
                        leftRotate(toFix.parent.parent); //case#2
                    }
                    toFix.parent.color = "black"; //case#3
                    toFix.parent.parent.color = "red"; //case#3
                    rightRotate(toFix.parent.parent); //case#3
                }

            }

        }
        root.color = "black";
    }
    // left rotation
    public void leftRotate(Node toRotate){
        Node parent = toRotate.right; //set parent
        toRotate.right = parent.left; // turn parent's left subtree into toRotate's right subtree
        if(parent.left != null){
            parent.left.parent = toRotate;
        }
        parent.parent = toRotate.parent; // link toRotate's parent to parent
        if(toRotate.parent == null){
            root = parent;
        }
        else if(toRotate.equals(toRotate.parent.left)){
            toRotate.parent.left = parent;
        }
        else{
            toRotate.parent.right = parent;
        }
        parent.left = toRotate; // put toRotate on parent's left
        toRotate.parent = parent;
    }

    // right rotation
    public void rightRotate(Node toRotate){
        Node parent = toRotate.left; //set parent
        toRotate.left = parent.right; // turn parent's right subtree into toRotate's left subtree
        if(parent.right != null){
            parent.right.parent = toRotate;
        }
        parent.parent = toRotate.parent; // link toRotate's parent to parent
        if(toRotate.parent == null){
            root = parent;
        }
        else if(toRotate.equals(toRotate.parent.right)){
            toRotate.parent.right = parent;
        }
        else{
            toRotate.parent.left = parent;
        }
        parent.right = toRotate; // put toRotate on parent's right
        toRotate.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

MAIN class:

```
public class RBtreeTester {

    static String dictionaryName = "dictionary.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RBtree testerTree = new RBtree();

        testerTree.addNode("hello");
        testerTree.addNode("bye");
        testerTree.addNode("hi");
        testerTree.addNode("goodbye");
        testerTree.addNode("goodmorning");
        testerTree.addNode("goodevening");

    }

}
```

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at RBtree$Node.access$8(RBtree.java:10)
    at RBtree.RBinsertFixUp(RBtree.java:53)
    at RBtree.addNode(RBtree.java:47)
    at RBtreeTester.main(RBtreeTester.java:13)
```

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace please

Comment: @Will I added it in. Some of the line numbers might not add up because I cut out some of the irrelevant code though. Also, let me know if you would like me to add in the tester class with main.

Comment: Post the real code, the real stack trace and tell which line numbers it refers to.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, what I did was a copied the shortened code that I posted on here and ran it in my environment and updated the produced stack trace (it should now match line for line). I also added the main class for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging code from stack traces alone is harder than debugging code that you've added [print statements](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/print-statements.html) to. You just need to remember to remove them before you submit the program (if it's homework) or ship it (if it's work work.)

In this case, though, I think the stack trace has all the information you need. If the node you've inserted is the new root node, its `parent` will be `NULL` when you call `RBinsertFixUp`, and the first thing `RBinsertFixUp` tries to do is access a method of the node's parent. This will cause Java to exit with a NullPointerException.

And you're right, Java code written by very experienced programmers tends to have fewer checks for `NULL`. That's not just a feature of the algorithm though; that's because they have practiced thinking through exactly where `NULL` can be encountered running their code, and know to only put checks there.

Comment: I've tried adding if(toInsert.parent != null) check before calling RBinsertFixUp(toInsert), but then the crash is at Line# 101 with another null pointer exception. This is what I originally meant. No matter how many null checks I make, I just keep getting them further on in the code and it starts to seem like it's just too excessive to be normal especially when implementing an algorithm from a book.

Comment: Consider whether you're doing the right thing in response to a NULL check. There are some times where you need to i.e. `return` from a method because the rest of it makes no sense once you've failed once.

Comment: It might help others help you if you post a reference to the book (i.e. a link to the author's website, or the book in Google Book Search or Amazon) and the page the algorithm is on. I probably don't have it with me, but someone else looking at the question might.

Comment: But there is nothing else after it... calling the fix up is the last thing that the addNode method does. The rest of the crashes are in fixUp with the nulls. Here is the exact book: http://bayanbox.ir/view/5225979443268640508/INTRODUCTION-TO-ALGORITHMS-.THIRD-EDITION.pdf Specifically, page# 316.